# FLASK unboundlocal error, while navigate through another page

Tags: python, html, jquery, mysql, flask

when i click on the username, it has to navigate to another page with the particular user information. to acheive this i tried with jquery, python and flask. But i was not able to achieve it, i get the error below.

[image]

Can anyone please help me. Is their anything wrong in the code.

Below is the code

app.py

```
app.route("/ajaxfile",methods=["POST","GET"])
def ajaxfile():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       userid = request.form['userid']
       cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = %s", [userid])
       result = cur.fetchall() 
    return render_template('detail.html', result=result)
```

index.html

```
 {% for row in emp %}    
  <tr>                
        <td>{{row.id}}</td>  
         <td><a data-id='{{row.id}}' class="userinfo btn btn-success" href="{{ url_for('ajaxfile') }}">{{row.name}}</a></td>  
  </tr>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.userinfo').click(function(){
                var userid= $(this).data('id');
                alert(userid)
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ajaxfile',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {userid: userid},
                    success: function(data){ 
                        
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

details.html

```
 {% for row in result %} 
 <table border='0' width='100%'>
 <tr>     
    <td style="padding:20px;">
    <p>Name : {{row.name}}</p>
    <p>Description : {{row.description}}</p>
    <p>Responsible person : {{row.responsibleperson}}</p>
    <p>Employee code : {{row.employeename}}</p>
    <p>Date : {{row.date_time}}</p>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have defined result variable within `if` scope which will executed if you make a post request. And you are returning result in render_template function .If no post request , the render_template function doesn't find any variable `result` so it gives error

Comment: @charchit can please suggest a solution for this. If i remove a if condition i get the 400 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory that you used variable result , before defining.

You are making ajax request to send data to flask. If you return any data within the if scope then it is stored in `data` param of `success` function in js.

You can't `render_template` in that way, you have two options

1. You should send data using forms, after which you can use `return render_template()` function in if scope. But you can't visit the detail page without a post request from index.html
2. You can send data using ajax and return the result variable in if scope.`return jsonify{"res":result}`, now `data` has the json and `data.res` has value of `result`  in `success` function. You can use the `for` loop of javascript and [append](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) data using jquery on the same page.
   Make a td tag , give it Id and use it in jquery.

If you give the full code , I can edit it and send or post it here. through github or discord.

edit: You can do it like this.

```
from flask import jsonify 
app.route("/ajaxfile",methods=["POST","GET"])
def ajaxfile():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       userid = request.form['userid']
       cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = %s", [userid])
       result = cur.fetchall()
       return jsonify{result=result}
    return "Hello world" # to avoid error, you can also allow only post methods by removing get from methods.
```

in html: You have to do this in the index.html file.

```
[...] 
<table border='0' width='100%'>
 <tr>     
    <td style="padding:20px;" id="my_td">
    
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

js: In success function.

```
 success: function(data){ 
   for (row of data.result){
   $("#my_td").append(`<p>Name : row.name</p><p>Description : row.description</p><p>Responsible person : row.responsibleperson</p><p>Employee code : row.employeename</p><p>Date : row.date_time</p>`)                           
      }
 }
```

**Method 2** Using Forms

Html : make a form tag and an hidden input whose value will be row.id

```
{% for row in emp %}    
<tr>
     <form action="/ajaxfile" method="POST">
          <input value="{{row.id}}" type="hidden" name="userid">
       <td>{{row.id}}</td>
     <td><button data-id='{{row.id}}' type="submit" class="userinfo btn btn-success" >{{row.name}}</button></td>
     </form>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Python: Keep everthing same and return render_template in if scope.

```
[...]
if request.method == 'POST':
     [...]
     return render_template('detail.html', result=result)
```

Comment: I have posted all the every code related to this questions. still if you want the code, please tell me how i have to share the code to you? still I'm not able to solve it from above answer. It would be helpful for me if you write it. As i'm not much familar with jquery and ajax

Comment: @ShwethaK You can contact me on discord `charchit#8198` or you can make a github repo and share it's link with me.

Comment: @ShwethaK I updated the answer, don't make a new html file rather add the above snippet in index.html. If you want to make a new file, then I can tell you the other method with forms.

Comment: i want to make new html file as detail.html with the all the information of user info.